# Project sequence so that each element will become sum of all before it with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a following code that transforms each element of an array into sum of all elements before it. The procedural implementation is as follows:

```
float[] items = {1, 5, 10, 100}; //for example
float[] sums = new float[items.Length];
float total = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++){
  total+=items[i];
  sums[i] = total;
}
```

How would I implement this as a LINQ one-liner? 
I know it can be done for example as

```
items.Select((x, i) => items.Take(i + 1).Sum())
```

but I think it's not very efficient when the array size grows, as it has to do Sum() for each element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ doesn't support this case very cleanly, to be honest - you want a mixture of aggregation and projection. You *can* do it with side-effects, which is horrible:

```
// Don't use this!
float sum = 0f;
var sums = items.Select(x => sum +=x).ToArray();
```

Side-effects in LINQ are nasty. Likewise you *can* do it using `Take`/`Sum` as shown by RePierre and L.B - but that takes an operation which is *naturally* O(N) and converts it into an operation which is O(N^2).

The [MoreLINQ project](http://morelinq.googlecode.com) I started a while ago does have support for this, in its [`Scan`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Scan.cs) and [`PreScan`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/PreScan.cs) members. In this case you want `Scan`, I believe:

```
var sums = items.Scan((x, y) => x + y);
```

If you don't want to use a third-party library, don't want to use side-effects, don't want the inefficiency of the `Take` solution, and *only* need addition, and *only* need it for a single type (e.g. `float` in your case) you can easily introduce your own method:

```
public static IEnumerable<float> RunningSum(this IEnumerable<float> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(source);
    }
    float sum = 0f;
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        sum += item;
        yield return sum;
    }
}
```

As you'll have noticed, this is basically the same code as your original - but is lazily evaluated and applies to *any* sequence of floats.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = items.Select((item, index) => items.Take(index).Sum() + item);
```

**EDIT**
You can use `Aggregate` method to create the sums:

```
var result = items.Aggregate(new List<float>(), (seed, item) =>
{
    seed.Add(seed.LastOrDefault() + item);
    return seed;
});
```

Comment: @JonSkeet, Jon, please see the edit - it's not the most elegant use of `Aggregate` method but it will do the work.

Comment: Yes, it will. At this point all that's lost is the streaming aspect. I think I'd personally prefer to use MoreLINQ or a dedicated method for this, but your idea is a nice one :)

Answer (score 1):

The Reactive Extensions team at Microsoft released an "Interactive Extensions" library that adds many useful extensions to `IEnumerable<T>`. One of them is `Scan` which does exactly what you want.

Here's the IX way of doing a running total:

```
IEnumerable<float> results = items.Scan(0.0f, (x1, x2) => x1 + x2);
```